# Error 1603 when installing Microsoft Intellipoint 8.2 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Installing MS Intellipoint 8.2 (for my MS touch mouse) on my Dell Inspiron 580  always gives the following error:
"Setup must close because an error occurred. Verify that your computer meets the system requirements on the product packaging. Restart your computer and try running Setup again. If this error happens again, see Help for customer support options. (Error Code 1603)"

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with all latest updates.
MS solutions don't work. How to fix?

Comment: Last resort, get your hands on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer_CleanUp_Utility and try clean up any leftovers.

Comment: Installer cleanup utility is dangerous to use, that is why Microsoft pulled it, it does more damage than good if used improperly, which most people do.

Comment: You don't need to install MS Intellipoint....Its a useless program that just takes up processor resources.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484)

Right click on the installer package and select "run as administrator", see if this gets it installed, if not read the link I posted.

.

> You may receive this error message if any one of the following conditions is true:
>
> The folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is encrypted.
>
> The drive that contains the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is accessed as a substitute drive.
>
> The SYSTEM account does not have Full Control permissions on the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to. You notice the error message because the Windows Installer service uses the SYSTEM account to install software.